# What is the procedure for taking and saving a snapshot from an IP camera in an Android app?

Tags: android

Right now I'm using HttpClient to gain admin rights to the camera, issuing the url command to take the snapshot, creating a directory on the phone to store the image, but I can't work out how to save the image inside that directory. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You would have to ask the manufacturer of the camera what their HTTP protocol is and how you download a photo given that you asked it to take one.

Comment: It's an Axis camera and I know how to request one (I'm pretty sure that part is working correctly) but I need to know how to save the image to the phone.